# binding keydown event to ("ENTER") key does not happen

Tags: jquery

I am trying to submit a form with keydown(enter) and send it by the function that I want. But when I hit enter, it shows a behaviour like when the type of HTML button is submit.

Here is my JQuery code:

```
$(".code").keydown(function (e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
         $("body").append("Keydown triggered.\n");
        sendConfirmPhoneNumberCode();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is my html:

```
<form class="newRegister-formBox basketForm" id="confirmPhoneNumberForm" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" id="returnUrl" value="@ViewBag.ReturnUrl" name="ReturnUrl">
    <div class="newRegister-formBox">
        <div class="formElement newRegister-input">
            <i class="fa fa-key loginIcone"></i>
            <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="code" id="code" class="form-control persianDigitInput" placeholder="enter code">
        </div>
        <div class="newRegister-button">
            <button type="button" id="send-confirm-phone-number-code" class="animateBtn greenAnimateBtn">
                <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                confirm
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is live show of code in this link: http://jsfiddle.net/a521k7yr/

Comment: try and change `$(".code").keydown` to `$("#code").keydown`

Comment: You attach the event to `$(".code")`, but there are no elements in your sample that have `class="code"`.

Comment: great. solved it